# Sorting a String list with Integer values in Java

Tags: java

I have a column VALUE in my table that contains:

```
`M_SYSCONFIG = 200600,2600000,700000600,110000600,150000600`
```

When I sort this list the result is:
     `110000600,150000600,110000600,200600,2600000,700000600`

However, I need the list to be sorted as follows (treat the strings as integers): 
    `200600,2600000,110000600,150000600,700000600`

This is the code I have right now for sorting the list:

```
    JSONArray jsArray = dbcon.callSelectRecords("SELECT CODE, VALUE FROM M_SYSCONFIG WHERE MODULE = 'LIMIT_CONFIG' AND CODE in (?,?,?,?) ORDER BY VALUE", ft_other_cn, ft_own_account, payment, purchase);

    for (int i = 0; i< jsArray.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject js = JSON.newJSONObject(jsArray.get(i).toString());
        String trasactionType = JSON.get(js, "CODE");
        String value = JSON.get(js, "VALUE");
        List<String> data = Arrays.asList(value.split(","));
        Collections.sort(data);
```

I need to obtain the results as strings because after sorting I want to apply the following code:

```
        StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder();
        if(ft_other_cn.equals(trasactionType)) {
            long limitOtherCimb = limit.getFtOtherCimbLimit();
            sbValue.append(limitOtherCimb).append(",");
            for(String values:data) {
                Long limitSysConfig = null;
                try {
                    limitSysConfig = Long.parseLong(values);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                if(limitSysConfig == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(limitSysConfig > limitOtherCimb) {
                    continue;
                }
                sbValue.append(limitSysConfig).append(",");
            }
            customerLimit.setFtOtherCnLimit(StringUtils.removeEnd(sbValue.toString(), ","));
```

Comment: Hint: Convert the values to numbers.

Comment: So you want to sort as numeric values not Strings

Comment: Instead of having list of strings create list of numerical types (possibly Long or even BigInteger depending on how big your numbers are). Then sorting it should be easier.

Comment: Of-topic : You read the DB and directly get a JSON, then work on the JSON to create a sorted list ? Why the JSON ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using biginteger because your numbers seems quite large. It's not the most efficient and optimized solution but yeah it will work

```
public static List<String> sortData(List<String> data){
            List<BigInteger>convertedData=new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        for (String s : data) 
        {
            //System.out.println(s);
         convertedData.add(new BigInteger(s));
        }
        Collections.sort(convertedData);
        List<String>sortedData=new ArrayList<String>();

        for (BigInteger b : convertedData) 
        {
            sortedData.add(String.valueOf(b));

        }
        return sortedData;
    }
```

Your code:

```
JSONArray jsArray = dbcon.callSelectRecords("SELECT CODE, VALUE FROM M_SYSCONFIG WHERE MODULE = 'LIMIT_CONFIG' AND CODE in (?,?,?,?) ORDER BY VALUE", ft_other_cn, ft_own_account, payment, purchase);

for (int i = 0; i< jsArray.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject js = JSON.newJSONObject(jsArray.get(i).toString());
    String trasactionType = JSON.get(js, "CODE");
    String value = JSON.get(js, "VALUE");
    List<String> data = Arrays.asList(value.split(","));
    List<String> sortedData=sortData(data);  **<------**
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert you string values to integers like this and then need to sort.

```
JSONObject js = JSON.newJSONObject(jsArray.get(i).toString());
    String trasactionType = JSON.get(js, "CODE");
    String value = JSON.get(js, "VALUE");
    List<String> data = Arrays.asList(value.split(","));
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(String s : data){
        intList.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
    }
    Collections.sort(intList);
```

Comment: i need String result, because i want to concat after that sorting.

Comment: @YeruAdi after sorting  you can again convert to string values

Comment: can you help me dude ? i try to convert but i can't

Comment: can you help me dude ? i try to convert but i can't @Muddassir Rahman

Answer (score 1):

Implement a Comparator like this:

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return new Long(Long.parseLong(o1)).compareTo(Long.parseLong(o2));
            }
        });
```

Comment: this sounds rather slow

Comment: i am sorry, because i am new here dude :)

Comment: That looks to be quite suboptimal. Casting all elements to int/long, comparing them and then casting back to strings would most likely be faster. If I'm correct you're performing about log(n) times more casts.

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of streams introduced in java 8.

Just add the below line after creating the List and you would have sorted string list

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList(value.split(","));

data=data.stream().mapToLong(Long::parseLong).sorted().mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you very large numbers you can use BigInteger

```
data=data.stream().map(BigInteger :: new ).sorted().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you are using java 6,7 you would have to use a comparator as mentioned by Taher

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return new Long(Long.parseLong(o1)).compareTo(Long.parseLong(o2));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to change your list, then the simplest way is to build a comparator using Java 8 and use the string values as bigintegers. You do not need to convert your string list to a number list.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("200600,2600000,700000600,110000600,150000600".split(","));

list.sort(Comparator.comparing(item -> new BigInteger(item)));

System.out.println(list);
```

The magic happens within

```
Comparator.comparing(item -> new BigInteger(item))
```

With this you are constructing a **Comparator** (which is needed for sorting), that compares all items converted to **BigIntegers**.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the numbers as Strings - as a string, 11 comes before 2. You need to first convert the array of strings to numbers, then sort them as numbers.

With the Streams API you can do that on one line:

```
String value = ...;
List<Long> data = Arrays.stream(value.split(",")).map(Long::new).sorted()
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since you need them as Long later, I'm using Long as the numeric type.